# Editing htaccess causes internal server error 500

Tags: .htaccess, internal-server-error

I download the htaccess file, add a 301 redirect rule to the end of it, upload the file to the server and it causes an Internal Server Error 500.

The weird thing is that when I remove the line I've added from the htaccess file and re-upload it, the Internal Server Error is still present and the site is broken.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: Did you add a permanent 301 redirect?

Comment: I added a 301 redirect then removed it when I realised it broke the site. The weird thing is that even uploading the file with the redirect completely removed wouldn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's wrong file coding. Open your .htaccess file in Notepad++. After running editor and entering the content into the edited htaccess file, click on the Format tab and make sure that the selected text encoding is UTF-8 (without BOM). Then save the file and resend it via FTP server (use FileZilla client). Maybe it help.

Comment: Thanks - ! edited the file in regular Windows 10 Notepad which doesn't have the option to change formatting I don't think? Where do you get Notepad++ from?

Comment: Thanks - I've downloaded the Notepad++ and when I load the file it shows it's currently encoded as 'Encode in UTF-8-BOM'.

Comment: I've just done a test and uploaded the saved file encoded with just UTF-8 and all has worked. Many thanks for your help.